# Ionic Pro "App ID already exists in project config"

Tags: ionic2

I logged in today and saw that my account was switched to "Ionic Pro". but now I can't see any of my apps.

I found the document [linking-an-existing-app](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/getting-started.html#linking-an-existing-app) where it says that I should run again `ionic link`, but then I receive the error:
`? App ID xxxxxx already exists in project config. Would you like to link a different app?`

If I click "yes" it shows my apps from the old `Ionic Cloud Dashboard` but how do I migrate all my apps to the new dashboard then ? the doc I shared above - doesn't really say. and I'm not using GitHub.

I also tried to re-login, doesn't help.

Comment: Apparently, you MUST use Git ( git & push your code ) - then you'll get your apps over there ... otherwise - you can't. that was the email from Ionic team. Since I don't want to share my personal code - gave up on Ionic Pro .... too bad